# Why won't my python script start a server on port 36296?

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a python script to start a server on port 36296 but it doesn't work at all, what went wrong here? When I tried to connect to port 36296, it said connection failed: connection refused. Please help explain why it is malfunctioning in such a peculiar way. Thank you. (I have tried this many times in many ways for a long time, so help would be EXTREMELY appreciated.)

```
import sys, time, logging, os, argparse

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab
from socketserver import TCPServer, StreamRequestHandler

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

from train import create_model, is_valid_track_code, INPUT_WIDTH, 
INPUT_HEIGHT, INPUT_CHANNELS

def prepare_image(im):
    im = im.resize((INPUT_WIDTH, INPUT_HEIGHT))
    im_arr = np.frombuffer(im.tobytes(), dtype=np.uint8)
    im_arr = im_arr.reshape((INPUT_HEIGHT, INPUT_WIDTH, INPUT_CHANNELS))
    im_arr = np.expand_dims(im_arr, axis=0)
    return im_arr

class TCPHandler(StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        if args.all:
            weights_file = 'weights/all.hdf5'
            logger.info("Loading {}...".format(weights_file))
            model.load_weights(weights_file)

        logger.info("Handling a new connection...")
        for line in self.rfile:
            message = str(line.strip(),'utf-8')
            logger.debug(message)

            if message.startswith("COURSE:") and not args.all:
                course = message[7:].strip().lower()
                weights_file = 'weights/{}.hdf5'.format(course)
                logger.info("Loading {}...".format(weights_file))
                model.load_weights(weights_file)

            if message.startswith("PREDICTFROMCLIPBOARD"):
                im = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
                if im != None:
                    prediction = model.predict(prepare_image(im), batch_size=1)[0]
                    self.wfile.write((str(prediction[0]) + "\n").encode('utf-8'))
                else:
                    self.wfile.write("PREDICTIONERROR\n".encode('utf-8'))

            if message.startswith("PREDICT:"):
                im = Image.open(message[8:])
                prediction = model.predict(prepare_image(im), batch_size=1)[0]
                self.wfile.write((str(prediction[0]) + "\n").encode('utf-8'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Start a prediction server that other apps will call into.')
    parser.add_argument('-a', '--all', action='store_true', help='Use the combined weights for all tracks, rather than selecting the weights file based off of the course code sent by the Play.lua script.', default=False)
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', type=int, help='Port number', default=36296)
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--cpu', action='store_true', help='Force Tensorflow to use the CPU.', default=False)
args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.cpu:
        os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
        os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"

    logger.info("Loading model...")
    model = create_model(keep_prob=1)

    if args.all:
        model.load_weights('weights/all.hdf5')

    logger.info("Starting server...")
    server = TCPServer(('0.0.0.0', args.port), TCPHandler)

    print("Listening on Port: {}".format(server.server_address[1]))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: can you please provide full error details.
there are several reasons for the connection refused.
1. port is already occupied by some process.